# PHP TCPDF moved permanently error on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, tcpdf

i have a problem with the TCPDF libary on my linux server. I write my project code in a windows system and it works perfectly. i render a html page into a variable and put it on a tcpdf page, this works perfect on my windows system. after this i moved the project to my linux server but if i run the php script the created pdf show me everytime in the pdf file the moved permanently error message. i dont understand why it work on the windows.

```
        $pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);


        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        $pdf->SetAuthor(****);
        $pdf->SetTitle(****);
        $pdf->SetSubject(*****);

        // Header und Footer Informationen
        $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
        $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

        $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

        $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 5, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
        $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);

        $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 35);

        // Image Scale 
        $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

        $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

        $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);

        $pdf->AddPage();

        $c = curl_init(*****);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $html = curl_exec($c);
        if (curl_error($c)){
            die(curl_error($c));
        }
        $status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($c);

        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

        //__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        $pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'webroot/files/1.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: 1. Check to make sure your web server doesn't have any redirects in it.
2. Make sure you don't have some other hard coded path that's windows specific.

Comment: the server dont have redirects

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved the problem, the problem was realy the redirect. but not the normal redirect from php. tcpdf cannot work with http to https over htaccess. i change the curl address to https and it works